# Poisson Process/Lévy process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I want to prove that a Poisson process fulfils the continuity in probability property (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Mathematical_definition)

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{P}(|N_{t+h}-N_{t}|> \epsilon) = 0$
whereas $N_t=\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{1}_{(0,t]} T_n$ ($t \geq 0$  Tn are the jumps)

so what I have:
$N_{t+h}-N_t =\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{1}_{(0,t+h]} T_n- \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{1}_{(0,t]} T_n= \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{1}_{[t,t+h]} T_n$

so it would be clear as $h \rightarrow 0$ then $N_{t+h}-N_t$ would equal zero, however how to prove it rigorously with the $\epsilon$ definition and how could I justify interchanging limit and probability?

Comment: My gut says use Markovs inequality.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the formalities of the matter are more complicated than it may appear; for a reference see [Cinlar, Ch. 4](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Stochastic-Processes-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486497976) or [Schilling, Khoshnevisan, Th. 3.4](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-34120-0)